# The green light is blinking on D5000 when I mount a Sigma 24-70 EX DG Macro

Tags: lens, sigma, nikon-d5000

I just got the lens. I know it doesn't autofocus on my camera body because it doesn't have built in motor but at least it should be usable in manual mode right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here. Got same problem. Pretty sure that the Sigma AF 24-70 F2.8 EX DG has a bug that it won't work with D5000. And it might not work with other non-motor body, e.g., D3000, D3100, etc. However, when used with cheap extension tube to take macro, it works. Damned strange.

Comment: What extension tube did you use? Does it support autofocus?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the autofocus indicator light in the bottom left of the screen.

When I'm using a manual focus lens on my D3000, this still lights up when the picture is in focus under the selected AF sensor. If I'm very out of focus, or the sensor is over something with no contrast to detect, then this light blinks the same way it does in autofocus mode.

Comment: No, its not the focus confirmation light but the memory access light. It keeps blinking and the camera doesn't respond to any button I pressed.

Comment: And it only happens when this lens is mounted? Weird. I'd suggest editing your question to specify which light is blinking.

Answer (score 0):

The Sigma lens should have an AF/MF selector - if you set it to Manual Focus, your lens should work as usual, because that confirms to the camera body that you're aware that you have to shoot with manual focusing.

If that doesn't work, try flicking the switch back and forth a couple of times; it may be that the sensor isn't working properly

If that doesn't work; try the lens on a different camera body; there might be a fault with the lens.

Good luck!

Comment: It works great with a D90 body. I can use it in manual or autofocus. Using a D5000 body the camera won't even boot to the menu.